# PropertyGrid, DefaultValue, Unknown Colors

Tags: c#, .net, propertygrid

To Any...To All,

My property grid is inspecting a class that has several color properties...

The colors are not system colors, nor 'Known' colors...

When displaying the colors the text value in the grid might look like this:

```
209, 175, 171
```

How do I define [Attribute] the Property so that when this color is chosen, the PropertyGrid understands that the default color has been chosen?

I have tried:

```
[DefaultValue(typeof(Color),"209 , 175, 171")]
[DefaultValue(typeof(Color),"209,175,171")]
```

No luck so far...

Thanks for any help...

This site rocks...it has helped me more than any other site as I trudge through this project...

Carson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried this in a Windows Forms app and it works fine. Here is my entire app:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = new Foo();
    }
}

public class Foo {
    [DefaultValue("foo")]
    public string MyString { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "209 , 175, 171")]
    public Color MyColor { get; set; }
}
```

And my form is a default form with a `PropertyGrid` control on it.

When the color is set to 209,175,171 it shows in normal text. If I change any value it shows up as bold. Similarly, when the string is set to any text it's bold and when I set it to "foo" then it shows in normal text.

With non-default values:

[image]

With default values:

[image]

Comment: That is bizarre...

When you include the extra white space after the first value in the string it works....

In other words this works:

[DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "209 , 175, 171")]  I would have never figured that out in a million years and went and made custom converter to deal with this....


This does not:

[DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "209, 175, 171")]

I have no idea why nor do I really care...

You answered and solved my problem

Cheers

Comment: Can you try that for Color.Black (0,0,0)...it does not seem to work when you set the default value with this :  [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "0 , 0, 0")]....niether does this: [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "Black")]  .....  I think it has to do with the fact that Black is a "Known" Color...just a hunch

Comment: For known colors you can also use [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "Black")]. I tried various combinations of spaces and/or the textual names (including "Black" and "0,0,0") and it all worked.

Comment: Its not working for either white or black for me...keep in mind that the default value is not an actual color but an int converted first via Color.FromARGB...which in turn is then converted again with the opacity or alpha at 255...in other words within the property I check if the var IsEmpty and if so do the double conversion to get the solid....EXAMPLE:  _ColorSunDay = Color.FromArgb(255, Color.FromArgb(Default.COLOR_SUN_DAY));...where Default.COLOR_SUN_DAY = 16777215... I cannot control the form or type of value which is int in this case for the default....stuck with it...

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. *DefaultValue(typeof(Color)* is not working for me.

I have to do this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyCar car1 = new MyCar();
        this.propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = car1;
    }

    public class MyCar{
        //*****************************
        private Color MyColor_ = Color.Red;//<------------------------ Here
        //*****************************
        public Color MyColor
        {
            get { return MyColor_; }
            set { this.MyColor_ = value; }
        }

        private String Id_;
        public String Id
        {
            get { return Id_; }
            set { this.Id_ = value; }
        }

    }
```

---

[image]

It works for me, I don't know where is the problem exactly.